# Insert a column with a conditional function into a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, function, if-statement, insert

I want to calculate the difference between open and close price but taking to account if a trade is a Buy/Sell.

I have the conditional function below; but l do not know how to insert a new column with the results into the original dataframe which has a list of trades and l am getting an error with this function.

def pl_gap(type):
if type in mt_trades['type'] == 'BUY':
mt_trades['close_price'] - mt_trades['open_price']
else:
mt_trades['open_price'] - mt_trades['close_price']

mt_trades['pl_gap'] = mt_trades.apply(pl_gap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also found out that this solution also works:

```py
mt_trades["pl_gap"] = mt_trades.apply(
    lambda row: (
        row["close_price"] - row["open_price"]
        if row["type"] == "BUY"
        else row["open_price"] - row["close_price"]
    ),
    axis=1,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def pl_gap(row):
    if row['type'] == 'BUY':
        return row['close_price'] - row['open_price']
    else:
        return row['open_price'] - row['close_price']

mt_trades['pl_gap'] = mt_trades.apply(lambda row: pl_gap(row), axis=1)
```